# Updating existing classes with new EDMX model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am working with an existing EDMX model where I had to add a new column to DB. I have updated the model from DB and now I can see the new column in the model. However, I have to update the Classes with the newly added column and add get; set; methods etc,. Is there an automate way to update this via Visual Studio  but still retain the existing code and add the new property in? This is the first time I'm using EDF an find it hard to get my head around it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: If you have additional logic for the generated entities, you should put them in a partial class so if you have to regenerate the entities, you don't lose anything. When you add/remove columns in database, you should be able to delete the entity from EDMX and redrop the table for it to regenerate the entity.

Comment: How are you generating your classes? If you are coding you own POCO entities, try using T4 Templates to generate the code, that way, anytime you change your model, you can just regenerate the class. And like @BalaR said, used partial classes for added functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the ADO.NET DbContext Generator to create model classes for you?  That's how I do it.  If you do that then, generally speaking, those classes will recreate correctly if you add a new column to a corresponding DB table.  Any code related to some generated I put in a separate viewmodel or other custom-built model that isn't subject to being overwritten when those are regenerated.  Then there's just some minor mods to my viewmodels if the DB changes.

Comment: The system uses POCO entities. I think I will have to regenerate using T4 template as @AJC describes. I did try updating using DBContext Generator.However, the code generated code is heavily customised. Therefore seperating logic to partial classes or models would be lot of re-engineering in the solution. I was expecting it to be a simple update!

Comment: @Chin: It is only simple until somebody make manual changes to autogenerated code.